# Wrap AES Key with RSA in Node.js Crypto library

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I am creating a random AES key for encrypting a data packet using the Node `Crypto` library like below:

```
    const createKey = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)  => {
            crypto.generateKey("aes", {length: 256}, (err, key) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                }

                resolve(key.export().toString());
            });
        });
    };
```

I then use this key to encrypt a data packet using `Crypto.createCiperiv`.

```
    //gets an AES key for this encryption
    const secretKey = await createKey();

    //encrypt data packet using AES key
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, iv);
    const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text), cipher.final()]);
```

Finally, I want to wrap the AES key in an RSA public key to be sent to a server, so the data is encrypted at rest.

My problem is that I do not see a way to wrap the AES key with an RSA key using the Node.js `Crypto` library to append to the data before being sent. I know a way exists using the `SubtleCrypto` class available in https context in the browser, but I was hoping to use Node `Crypto`. Is there a way to wrap the AES key and append the encrypted string/data to the packet sent to the server using Node `Crypto` or do I need to rewrite my code to use all `SubtleCrypto`?

Comment: _...My problem is that I do not see a way to wrap the AES key with an RSA key using the Node.js Crypto library..._: There are many examples on the web about RSA encryption, e.g. [here](https://www.sohamkamani.com/nodejs/rsa-encryption/).

Comment: You are talking about **hybrid encryption** and a full running example with Node's crypto extension is here (disclaimer: I'm the author): https://github.com/java-crypto/cross_platform_crypto/blob/main/RsaAesGcmHybridEncryptionString/RsaAesGcmHybridEncryptionNodeJsCrypto.js. The runnable version is here: https://replit.com/@javacrypto/CpcNodeJsCryptoRsaAesGcmHybridStringEncryption#index.js/. Both examples use AES-256 in GCM mode for encryption and RSA OAEP SHA 1 encryption with a 2048er key.

Comment: @Topaco can you post that as an answer, so I can accept it? I had tried googling before posting and came up empty, but that example was exactly what I needed. Thanks!